# Inconveniente al ejecutar el servidor con runserver en Python ( python manage.py runserver)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cordial saludo, necesito pedirles un favor acerca de lo siguiente:

Estoy realizando un curso de Django siguiendo el canal de píldoras informáticas en unos de los videos se necesita realizar el proceso para acceder al servidor mediante la siguiente instruccion (python manage.py runserver):

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\ProyectosDjango\TiendaOnline> python manage.py runserver
Me muestra los siguientes errores:
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    return {(migration.app, migration.name): migration for migration in self.migration_qs}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1187, in execute_sql
    return list(result)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1586, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1586, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\utils.py", line 6, in utc_tzinfo_factory
    raise AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")
AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC
```

Al ingresar a cualquier explorador ya sea Google Chrome o Microsoft Edge, e intentar acceder al servidor mediante la url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/), no me muestra el servidor, me muestra la pagina desagradable que dice

```
No se puede acceder a este sitio web
La página 127.0.0.1 ha rechazado la conexión.
Prueba a:
•   Comprobar la conexión
•   Comprobar el proxy y el cortafuegos
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Agradezco de antemano su colaboración.

Comment: Hola hrmar, viendo la traza del error, este hace mención a un problema con tu base de datos y el formato UTC, puede ser que tengas pendientes alguna migración. Revisa eso y me comentas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias un cordial saludo desde Colombia, he seguido paso a paso el proceso en cuanto a las migraciones, el inconveniente parece ser que es más por los lados de la base de datos PostgreSQL o quizás por la versión del Visual Studio Code:

Los datos de la base de datos PostgreSQL(pgAdmin4),  son los siguientes:

Version
7.4
Application Mode
Desktop  Y la version de Visual Studio es la 1.81.1                                              
Electron:22.3.18
ElectronBuildId:22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1 
La base de datos está funcionando bien, saludos!.